# I am Getting this error while creating a new component in Angular 2.!

Tags: angular

I have created the new component in angular 2 and I am getting this error "Individual declaration in merged declaration 'MyComponentComponent' must be all exported or all local." As I am new to angular 2 I am not able to figure out the error on code need help.! Thanks in advance ..!

Comment: The code of your component would be welcome ;-)

Comment: I got this error when the automatic refactorinf imported the type that I was working on. So I imported the same class

Answer (score 11):

I think that you have several classes with the same name `MyComponentComponent`. When defining a component, you need to take a new name for its implementation class.

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Component1 {
  (...)
}

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Component2 {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Actually i have miss placed the directives code I put my code in the same class that is why the error came but now I place the same code in the file where I have to render the code so I put it in app.component.ts file. and it works. :) ..!!